# How to debug TypeScript server side code of NextJS using WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, debugging, next.js, webstorm, app-route

How to debug NextJS API in WebStorm. Also, I am using TypeScript and the app route as it is quite difficult to debug the API using `console.log()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this:

1. Open the `Run > Edit Configurations...` dialog in WebStorm.
2. Click the `+` button to add a new configuration, then select `Node.js`.
3. Give your configuration a meaningful name, such as “Debug Next.js with Yarn”.
4. In the `Working directory`, choose the root directory of your Next.js project.
5. For the `JavaScript file` field, instead of pointing directly to a file, you will use the Yarn command. Therefore, set the Node interpreter to the Node.js binary path, and in the `Node parameters` field, enter the path to the Yarn binary (usually `/usr/bin/yarn` or simply `yarn` if it's in your system’s PATH).
6. In the `Application parameters` field, type `dev` to run Next.js in development mode.
7. Confirm the setup by clicking `OK`.

Comment: Thanks it's save my life and as i am using nvm i have to make some changes and my final configuration is

Node Interpreter: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node
Node Parameters: /usr/local/bin/yarn